# Process multiple files via command line

Tags: python, cmd

I want to run a Python Script to process multiple images: Currently I'm using a simple command line to process a single image

```
python script.py --input C:\Users\file1.png --output C:\Users\file1_output.png
```

Comment: you need to change the --input/--output to a string array[]... can you post the script.py?

Comment: You need to decide the API you want. Do you want alternating `--input in1.png --output out1.png --input in2.png --output out2.png …` (kind of like ImageMagick `convert`)? If so, what happens if they write `--input in1.png --output out1.png --output out2.png`? Or maybe you want something like `--outsuffix _output file1.png file2.png file3.png`? Or… well, there are lots of options; look around at some other tools and see what they do and decide what you want to do. If you can't figure out how to implement it (probably with `argparse` or a third-party library), ask for help where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the argument being passed into your program is a string, you could just comma separate the different file paths and then split them in the program with `.split()`

Or another option is to specify a folder path where all the image files are located, and then use `glob.glob('path/*.png')` to get a list of all files with the .png extension.